# Values in <head> are passed into <body> wordpress uses Template Page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

My web: [quanghong.vn](https://quanghong.vn) URL demo: https://quanghong.vn/test-page/

Values in <head> are passed into <body> wordpress uses Template Page.

The code I used is completely correct!! I don't understand anything wrong!! Thanks

[image]

View

[image]

Code

[image]

I've tried deleting and redoing a lot, but it still doesn't work!